# Automount for USB sticks and disks stoped working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, automount, 21.04, usb-drive

since last weekend the automount for my USB sticks and disk stopped working on my Ubuntu 20.10.
Before I just input my USB stick. It has been automatically mounted and was accessable via Nautilus file explorer and via the mount point "/media//".

The USB device is still displayed in the Nautilus explorer but when I open the device I get displayed the error message

**"Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media//: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (udisks-error-quark, 0)"**

[Mount error messages in Nautilus explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGy0G.png)

I could mount the USB device manually, but it was not possible to mount it with write permissions. I tryed a lot of mount options in the /etc/fstab such as

**/dev/sda1 /media/sda1 ntfs rw,suid,nodev,exec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,nls=utf8,errors=continue,user**

I got always only read permissions :(

After I tried a lot I updated my Update **from 20.10 to 21.04**. But this didn't solve my problem :(

Do you have an idea how I can re-activate or fix the automount feature for USB storage devices again?

Many thanks for your help!

Regards, Roland

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  *Your question very strongly highlights the off-topic 20.10 release; with only minor mention of on-topic 21.04*

Comment: `fsck` or perform a *file-system* check on your device, and if errors are found, and fixed, it'll work correctly again I bet.